# добавить товары из Custom Related Products for WooCommerce и показать в корзине с родительским товаром - WordPress

Tags: php, woocommerce

WooCommerce.

Цель.

есть вариативный товар "Пицца". сделать возможность, чтобы при покупке пиццы была возможность добвлять доп товары, например колбаса, сыр и т.д. и при этом менялась цена и вес заказанной пиццы.

Поставил плагин Custom Related Products for WooCommerce . с помощью него прикрепляю к пицце нужные товары http://prntscr.com/ajtcln . в карточке товара разобрался как их вывести, с добавлением веса думаю разберусь , с ценой тоже. но как сгенерировать ссылку на добавление этих товаров в корзину как бы одним товаром и чтобы в корзине увидеть не как 3 отдельных товара, а один заказ "пицца. добавки: колбаса,сыр" и общая цена.